# What is a specific word for someone who can't feel any emotions and can't understand emotions or more specifically love?

Tags: single-word-requests

I know a word such a loveless, "without love" can describe such a person but can anyone be more specific in the type of word I seek?

Comment: Someone who can't feel any emotions could be called a "psychopath," but that's clearly not what you mean. If your focus is on love then perhaps you could dispense with the "more specifically" and instead actually be completely specific.

Comment: Technically this person would be exhibiting symptoms of some sort of psychological disorder.  Depending on the precise symptoms he could be a psychopath or someone with autism, maybe a few others.

Comment: Can you provide some context? How do you want to use the word? It could be as a medical diagnosis or describing a character in a work of fiction. Each of those would probably lead to different words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**callous**

insensitive; indifferent; unsympathetic:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/callous?s=t

**apathetic**

having or showing little or no emotion:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/apathetic?s=t

You could also try **dispassionate**; **phlegmatic**; **impervious to feelings**

Answer (score 1):

Clinically speaking, one who cannot feel emotion is said to be *[emotionally detached](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emotional_detachment)*, although the term is also applied to people who can feel emotion but who choose to avoid situations for expressing emotion.  They may do this because of anxiety of stress.

A more specific term is *[alexithymia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexithymia)* (from the Greek meaning "having no words for emotions").  Alexthymics have difficulty in identifying and describing their own emotions or in detecting emotions in others.

Answer (score 0):

From WordNet (r) 3.0 (2006) [wn]:

```
impassive
  adj 1: having or revealing little emotion or sensibility; not
         easily aroused or excited; "her impassive remoteness";
         "he remained impassive, showing neither interest in nor
         concern for our plight"- Nordhoff & Hall; "a silent
         stolid creature who took it all as a matter of
         course"-Virginia Woolf; "her face showed nothing but
         stolid indifference" [syn: {impassive}, {stolid}]
  2: deliberately impassive in manner; "deadpan humor"; "his face
     remained expressionless as the verdict was read" [syn:
     {deadpan}, {expressionless}, {impassive}, {poker-faced},
     {unexpressive}]
```